# JQuery UI Dialog - only the first link works

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a list of products from a particular supplier being displayed in a `<table>` populated with data from my mysql database.

Within this table, each product has a link that, when clicked, should show the product details in a ui-dialog, `<div id = "detalhe_produto"></div>`. The dialog does open, however, it only works only for the first item in the list. The other links of the following lines do not open the dialog.

Can anyone help me?

Here's the script I am using to open the ui-dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 

 $('detalhe_produto').click(function(){ 

     var selectedVal=$("#detalhe_produto").val(); 
     var url="produto_detalhe.php?codigo="+selectedVal; 

        var dialog = $("#detalhe_produto"); 
        if ($("#detalhe_produto").length == 0) { 
            dialog = $('<div id="detalhe_produto" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body'); 
        } 
        dialog.load( 
            url, 
            {},
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { 
                dialog.dialog({                        
                    close: function (event, ui) {                             
                        dialog.remove(); 
                    }, 
                    modal: true, 
                    width: 460 
                }); 
            } 
        ); 
    });  

});
</script>
```

and then the code table:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="lista_produto"><a href="#<?php $_SESSION['codigo_produto'] = $row_lista_produtos['codigo']; $_SESSION['produto'] = $row_lista_produtos['produto']; ?>"><?php echo $row_lista_produtos['codigo']; ?></a></td>
        <td width="15"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_lista_produtos = mysql_fetch_assoc($lista_produtos)); ?>
</table>
```

I have tried to change the `href="#"` to `href="javascript: void (0)"`
and the result was the same.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the HTML source from viewing in browser?

Comment: I'd like to, but the code is too big...
I'll put the code in a .txt format, so you can access it, ok?
here it is:
http://www.eastvet.com.br/code.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many distinct dialogs that can be clicked open, you need to use a class selector, `.` instead of an ID selector, `#`. You may have also forgotten the `#`.

So instead of this:

```
var dialog = $("#detalhe_produto");
```

do this:

```
var dialog = $(".detalhe_produto");
```

****Please see this jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/uFDdb/2/

It has a complete working demonstration of the jqueryUI dialog for multiple dialogs specific to your use case. Meaning, the dialog shows a value specific to which link was clicked.

Comment: Hi there! I've try this before, but the problem is...
    <a href="#<?php $_SESSION['codigo_produto']">
It feeds dynamicaly the ui-dialog... but all the data is in the same div...
What do you think about it?

ps.: sorry about my terrible english.

Comment: This is my div":
<div id="detalhe_produto" title="<?php echo $_SESSION['produto'] ?>" class="ui-dialog detalhe_produto"><?php include ('produto_detalhe.php') ?></div>

Comment: @pcsi hi, PHP is not the problem. Having only one dialog is also ok. Using jQuery you will just put product details in that dialog specific to whatever is clicked. The key to clicking one product vs. another is to use the `this` keyword as I've done in the jsfiddle. `$(this)` refers to what was clicked. You can't click on the dialog itself as it is hidden. But you can click one of the rows, `tr`. When you click on one of the rows, you need to associate data with that clicked row. So you need to plug in PHP into `selectedVal` like this: `var selectedVal=$(this).find('input').val("<?=$xxx?>");`

Comment: man... you're genious! I'll try put this to work and I'll back with my results soon. xD

Answer (score 1):

you missed a `#` in `$('detalhe_produto').click(function(){`

Comment: Yes, but the same thing happens. ^^